# Android onCreate - Syntax error on token "Override", delete this token

Tags: android, listview, overriding, public

When i was trying to implement display array values and images in listview it shows red line error delete override token of oncreate and in listview public identifier also showing red line error.

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ScanNow extends Activity{
    ListView listView;
    public Integer[] imgid = {R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image4,
            R.drawable.image6,R.drawable.image7,R.drawable.image8,R.drawable.image9,
            R.drawable.image10,R.drawable.image11,R.drawable.image12,R.drawable.image13};
    SampleAdapter sAdapter;
    public String[] imageNames ={"Deli Purchase of $5 or more","20-oz. or Large Market Pantry frozen chicken item","64-oz. Market Pantry juice or juice cocktails","With Purchase of any two Betty Crocker items","4.2-lb. or larger Kingsford charcoal","Engergizer batteries","$10 or higher Energizer flashlight","With purchase of any two axe items","Fresh fruit purchase of $5 or more","Fresh meat purchase of $5 orr more","Fresh vegetable purchase of $5 or more","With purchase of two 5-oz. or larger Market Pantry cheeses"};
    public String[] imagePrice ={"$2 off","$1 off","$1 off","75ç off","1$ off","1$ off","2$ off","1$ off","$1 off","$1 off","$1 off","$1 off"};


    Context ct;
    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scannow);
        ct=this;
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        sAdapter=new SampleAdapter(ct);
        listView.setAdapter(sAdapter);

    }
   class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    LayoutInflater li;
    Context c;
    ImageView img;
    TextView price,desc;
    Override
    public SampleAdapter(Context ct1) {
        c=ct1;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return imgid.length;
    }

    Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        li=(LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        arg1=li.inflate(R.layout.barcode_products_freeitemcell, null);
        img=(ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.priceimage);
        price=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.priceoff);
        desc=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.pricedesc);
        img.setImageResource(imgid[arg0]);
        price.setText(imagePrice[arg0]);
        desc.setText(imageNames[arg0]);
        return arg1;
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write `@override` instead of `override`